# Change photo date taken to value in date modified

Tags: applescript, automator

I came across an old set of photo's taken in the 90's.
These photo's have 2 dates in the exif. A date modified (the correct date) and a date taken (a date somewhere last year). When importing this into my photo database it has the wrong date associated.

I'd like to run an apple automator or applescript to copy the modified date into the taken date.

Anyone willing to help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

**Please make a backup first, and then just run the following commands in a directory that is a COPY of your files.**

You can do that with **exiftool** which you can install using **homebrew** with:

```
brew install exiftool
```

I believe the command you want in Terminal is:

```
exiftool "-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal<FileModifyDate" image.jpg
```

Just do one file for now, and check before and after with:

```
exiftool image.jpg
```

If it all looks good, you can do all the files with:

```
exiftool "-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal<FileModifyDate" *.jpg
```

Comment: Whilst this does correctly change the  `exif:DateTimeOriginal` value, it's good practice to reflect the date change(s) to other related properties too. For instance; a file that was modified in _PhotoShop_ (or other _Adobe_ app) typically inherits  an additional  `xmp:CreateDate` property - (derived from `exif:DateTimeOriginal` or `exif:DateTimeDigitized`). In this scenario you can sync both _exif_ and _xmp_ related dates by running: `exiftool "-exif:DateTimeOriginal<FileModifyDate" "-xmp:CreateDate<FileModifyDate"`. Unfortunately `exif:DateTimeDigitized` is read only so it can't be changed.